# Determine the numbers a and b that check the equality $\sqrt{\overline{aba}}=(a+b-1)\cdot \sqrt{a+b}$

Tags: linear-algebra, radicals, square-numbers, complex-multiplication

Determine the numbers a and b that check the equality

$\sqrt{\overline{aba}}=(a+b-1)\cdot \sqrt{a+b}$

**MY IDEAS**

I thought of decomposing $\overline{aba}$ as $101\cdot a + 10\cdot b$

Then i thought that the radicals are making the equation harder so I raised everything to the power of 2.

$101\cdot a + 10\cdot b= {(a+b-1)}^{2}\cdot (a+b)$

OTHER THINGS I THOUGHT OFF;

[image]

What should I donext? I tried descomposing the ${(a+b-1)}^{2}$, but didn't get anything helpful.
Any idea is welcome! Thank you!!

Comment: What does the $\overline{aba}$ notation mean?

Comment: It means the number that has 100a+10b+a... is a number...

Comment: You must say what kind of numbers are $a$ and $b$ because there is an infinity of reals $(a,b)$ as solution.

Comment: @Piquito It's normal that a and b are numbers between 0 and 9 because they are inside a number...

Comment: @Piquito $a,b$ are _digits_, and the notation $\overline{aba}$ means "a $3$-digit number with digits $a,b,a$ in that order".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got to this point:

$$\overline{aba}=(a+b-1)^2(a+b)$$

Now note that the right side only depends on $a+b$, and consider the possible values of $a+b$.  You get $6\le a+b\le 10$ (as for $a+b\le 5$ is too small and $a+b\ge 11$ is too big to get a $3$-digit number on the right side).

For the values of $a+b$ between $6$ and $10$ you get the following table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}a+b&(a+b-1)^2(a+b)\\\hline6&150\\7&252\\8&392\\9&576\\10&810\end{array}$$

Nice. So only for $a+b=7$ the number is of the form $\overline{aba}$. Also, as it happens, with $a=2, b=5$ we *do* have $a+b=7$. So $a=2, b=5$ is the unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you ask about $a,b$ integers because if not for each real $a$ you have a real $b$ for which $$101\cdot a + 10\cdot b= {(a+b-1)}^{2}\cdot (a+b)$$
We deduce the equation $$\frac{91a}{a+b}+10=(a+b-1)^2$$ It follows the possible cases are $$a+b=91a,7a,13a,7,13$$ and the only valid of them is $a+b=7$ from which the only solution $(a,b)=(2,5)$.

Comment: "It follows the possible cases are..." : Aren't you assuming there that $a$ is prime? (Which is not justified.)